# Spring Boot 2.5 Upgrade - Objects in SpringBootTest executed in Spock appear to be overwritten

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I am having an issue running some integration tests that are run using the Spock framework after upgrading my application.

I've got a configuration that returns a "Mock" object that is an extension of a class. The class that is extended contains several members of type HashMap that are initialized on declaration.

If I manually instantiate that object before my @Bean method returns it, it has all of the attributes instantiated. In this case, it has several members that are initialized by default to LinkedHashMaps. However, the object that is returned by the @Bean method has those attributes assigned to null. So somehow the members are set to null, or the object is replaced altogether.

Note that the accessors for those maps are generated by lombok. I see in the debugger that the Bean for that class has those accessors defined in its meta information. The attributes themselves are null.

My upgrade is from 2.1.9 to 2.5. The tests are written in Groovy and executed in Spock. The "Mock" subclass is written and instantiated in an @TestConfiguration annotated class, but its superclass is written in Java with the lombok annotations. This used to work in Spring 2.1.9 but is breaking in 2.5. I've started the application with debug=true but none of the output has provided any clues/leads.

Any ideas here would be helpful. Let me know if I can provide further information to assist your answer. Thanks in advance!

The Configuration Class:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {
    ...
    ...

    @Bean
    public MyCache spendAndMetricsCache() {
        CacheTestExtension myCache = new CacheTestExtension();
        return new CacheTestExtension();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

The super class:

```
public class MyCache implements Reloadable {

private static final int HOUR_AND_DAY_LOOKBACK_DAYS = 2;
private static final int WEEK_LOOKBACK_DAYS = 8;

@Builder.Default @Getter
private Map<Long, TObjectLongHashMap<String>> lifetimeMetrics = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Builder.Default @Getter
private Map<Long, TObjectLongHashMap<String>> monthlyMetrics = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

...
...
}
```

The Extended Test Class:

```
public class CacheTestExtension extends MyCache {

  protected Set<Integer> twoDayQueryIntervalIds() {
    return new HashSet<>();
  }


  protected Set<Integer> eightDayQueryIntervalIds() {
    return new HashSet<>();
  }
}
```

Note that in the debugger I stop after instantiating the CacheTestExtension the HashMaps assigned to the member variables are initialized to empty maps. After my context is wired together with Autowiring, the reference to the cache is to an instance of the CacheTestExtension, but the member variables are null.

Comment: Do you have a minimum example which shows what you mean?

Comment: I agree with Tim. Please understand that on StackOverflow it is customary to **show** code, not **describe** it only. The description is great as an add-on, but not as a stand-alone question. No developer can compile and debug prose in order to understand and reproduce your problem. So your chances of getting helpful answers when asking like this are minimal, not because nobody wants to help you but simply because nobody can. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: @tim_yates - Thank you for taking time to look at my post. I apologize for not leaving code initially. I've added some fragments and comments that might help you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe you misunderstood the terms MCVE (please read the link I posted before!) or "minimal example". Minimal does not mean "too little to reproduce" but "just enough to reproduce". An incoherent set of code snippets cannot be compiled or run. Besides, you are asking about Spock, but did not even show the Spock test either. This is like asking someone to repair your car without giving them access to same car. I think, like this you are not going to get your question reopened. So please improve it. Thank you.